# 0.5V virtual ground with single rail op amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-regulator

[EDIT]

I am working on a 0.5~3.3V voltage source with 0.5V virtual ground. Any problem with the design so far? (The high side probably needs to be switched to a class AB amplifier as well)

[image: 0.5~3.3V Voltage Regulator]

<strike>I am designing a 0.5~3.3V voltage source with 0.5V virtual ground. My question is, if there is no R28 (right most resistor), and VREG/VGND aren't connected to anything, would there be a stability problem on U3.2 ? Any suggestion on improvement?</strike>

([original schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJSuh.png))

Comment: "Any problem with the design so far?" Other than being really hard to read?  Hard to say without knowing what it's intended to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If VGND is 0.5V and is sinking current, what would the voltage at the base of Q21 need to be?

If VREG is 3.88V and is sourcing current, what would the voltage at the base of Q23 need to be?

Comment: I didn't quite understand why you asked the questions, but I put the circuit under simulator. Turns out the op-amp of my choice couldn't source/sink enough current to drive the transistors. I tried various configuration but couldn't get acceptable result. I have changed my direction on how to tackle the problem I was trying to solve.

Comment: @daniel Sorry for being opaque. The answer for the questions is 0.5V - Vbe, and 3.88V + Vbe. With the Darlingtons you're using, Vbe is approximately 1.2V, so -0.7V and 5.08V, but there's nothing in the circuit that could produce a voltage below ground or above 5V.